# How do I add a low_disk_space class to cfengine3 if my disk is more than 90% full?

Tags: cfengine

I would like to set a class in cfengine3 so I can perform an action if the disk is almost full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I did it. The `repair_failed` mnemonic doesn't really fit the "we detected there was less free disk space than you wanted" since it attempts no repair, but it seems to be the way to add a class as a result. It gives a perfectly fine explanation of the free disk space without the extra `ohno` class, but eventually I want to clear temp directories, vacuum databases, etc. as a reaction to the condition...

```
bundle agent storage
{
storage:
    "/" volume => low_disk_space;

reports:
    ohno::
       "Oh noes!";
}

body volume low_disk_space {
        freespace => "10%";
        repair_failed => { "ohno" };
}
```

Comment: Indeed, the storage is a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [diskfree](http://www.cfengine.org/manuals/cf3-reference.html#Function-diskfree) that return the available space on the partition

Here is a simple example (yes, I have a lot of free space) :

```
body common control {
    bundlesequence => { "test_free_space" };
}

bundle agent test_free_space {
    vars:
        "free" int => diskfree("/home");
        "min_free_space" int  => "200000000";
    classes:
        "not_enough_size" expression => isgreaterthan("$(min_free_space)", "$(free)");

    reports:
        not_enough_size::
            "There is not enough space left on /home";
}
```

Regards